# c# Vector2Int outside of unity where to get?

Tags: c#, vector2

I need Vector2Int implementation in c#. I need it for my console application, so i dont use unity. Is there a package that has this vector2?

Comment: I don't know what it does but it looks like the source is here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2Int.cs

Comment: Second result on Google for "Vector2Int unity code": https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Vector2Int.cs

Comment: Software & library recommendations are explicitly of topic.  There is `System.Drawing.Point`, but I find that implementation lacking in functionality. But it is really not that difficult to make your own implementation.